# XPath with different node path

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to come up with the correct XPath for getting a node based on a condition that isn't part of the XPath to be selected using the `XDocument.XPathSelectElement` method in C#.

So let's say I have the following XML.

```
<Root>
    <Parties>
        <Party>
            <Person>
                <Name>Bob Smith</Name>
            </Person>
            <Role>
                <Type>Borrower</Type>
            </Role>
        </Party>
        <Party>
            <Person>
                <Name>Mary Smith</Name>
            </Person>
            <Role>
                <Type>CoBorrower</Type>
            </Role>
        </Party>
    </Parties>
</Root>
```

So what I want to get is the value of

```
//Root/Parties/Party/Person/Name
```

where

```
//Root/Parties/Party/Role/Type
```

is 'Borrower'.

Based on my research before posting the question I thought the following might work but no luck.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elm = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Root/Parties/Party[./Role/[Type = 'Borrower']/Person/Name");
```

But this code gives me the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>   Additional information: Expression must evaluate to a `node-set`.

Comment: `//Name[./following::Type="Borrower"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath expression:

```
//Root/Parties/Party[Role/Type/text() = 'Borrower']/Person/Name
```

It gives you the desired result

```
Bob Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one:

//Type[.="Borrower"]/parent::node()/preceding-sibling::node()//Name